# What is this ==- javascript operator?

Tags: javascript

I was stumbling around trying different conditions, when I discovered `==-`, or `==+`.

In a JS console, you can write:

```
var a = " ";
```

then the following is true

```
a == " ";
```

but this is false

```
a == "    ";
```

However, it will be true if you say:

```
a ==- "   ";
```

or

```
a ==+ "   ";
```

So what is this nifty `==-` operator?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Answer (score 10):

They're not distinct operators.

Writing:

```
a ==- " ";
```

gets parsed as:

```
(a) == (-" ");
```

The same goes for `==+`.

The expression evaluates to `true` because of Javascript's weird type conversion rules. Something like the following occurs:

1. the unary `-` (or `+`) operators converts its operand to a number. If it's a blank string, the result of this conversion is `0`.
2. `a == (-" ")` is then equivalent to `" " == 0`. If types compared with `==` are different, one (possibly both), get converted to get a common type. In this case, the `" "` on the left-hand side gets converted to `0` too.
3. You end up comparing `0` to `0`, which yields `true`.

(The above is a rough example of how Javascript might come to this result, the [actual rules](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) are buried in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/). You can use the `===` operator instead to prevent the conversions and get `false` if the types of the compared objects are different.)

Answer (score 3):

It's simply a `==` followed by a `-` (or `+`).

(In the following I write `"<four spaces>"` to mean the string consisting of four spaces.)

That is, if you do `" " ==- "<four spaces>"`, you compare `" "` to `-"<four spaces>"`. `-"<four spaces>"` evaluates to `0`, since applying the minus converts to integer. Thus, you actually do `" " == 0`, which is true, since it converts the `" "` to an integer for the comparison.

`" " == "<four spaces>"` is false, however, as you're comparing two different strings.

Answer (score 1):

That is NOT an operator. You get those results because `-` and `+` is casting the string to a number, in this case, an empty string casts to the number `0` which is then interpreted as `false`, plus the equals operator `==` will cause some trouble with comparison and casting, that's why it's recommended to always use the `===` operator and you'll get the results you're after:

```
console.log(a === ' '); // true
console.log(a === '   '); // false
console.log(a === -'   '); // false
console.log(a === +'   '); // false
```